# Not able to hit 2nd services with generated Token

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, soap, drupal-services

I have been provided with two services in which ist service is used for login purpose and it will return an xml node token which i to be added as the header in all other services call,

In the attached sample code there are two functions in function **CreateObject()** i am hitting login service and am successfully able to get the response and from response i fetched the token and call other function with token **search(string token)** and passed the token in  header but its giving an exception `[System.Net.WebException] = {"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}`

But when i see in chrome Advanced Rest Client its giving the expected response

any suggestion or solution in right direction will be highly appreciable

Please See The Code Below

```
 private  void CreateObject()
    {        
        try
        {
            string abc = "";
            Stream datastream;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.example.com/abc/login");
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            String postData = "";
            request.Method = "POST";
            postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "sample", "sample");
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            datastream = request.GetRequestStream();
            datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);


            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
            String sourceCode = "";
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream))
            {
                sourceCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            int pos = sourceCode.IndexOf("<?");
            string xmlpart = sourceCode.Substring(pos);
            //XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(sourceCode);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlpart);
            XmlNodeList objNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("token");
           string tokens = objNodeList[0].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
          search(tokens);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

     public void search(string token)
        {
            Stream datastream;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/services/suggestions/search");
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
           // request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
           request.Headers.Add("x-csrf-token", token);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Accept = "application/x-cdf,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            String postData = "";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            postData = String.Format("param1={0}&param2={1}&param3={2}&param4={3}&param5={4}&param6={5}&param7={6}&param8={7}", "0", "1","1","1","0","1","2015-06-22","2015-06-22");
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            datastream = request.GetRequestStream();
            datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);


            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
            String sourceCode = "";
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream))
            {
                sourceCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out what was the issue

i was creating new cookie container for both the request

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

thus server was unable to authenticate

Error was resolved by using this code

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    private  void CreateObject()
        {        
            try
            {
                string abc = "";
                Stream datastream;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.example.com/abc/login");
                request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.Accept = "application/xml";
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                String postData = "";
                request.Method = "POST";
                postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "sample", "sample");
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                datastream = request.GetRequestStream();
                datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);


                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
                String sourceCode = "";
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream))
                {
                    sourceCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                int pos = sourceCode.IndexOf("<?");
                string xmlpart = sourceCode.Substring(pos);
                //XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(sourceCode);
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xmlpart);
                XmlNodeList objNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("token");
               string tokens = objNodeList[0].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
              search(tokens);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

         public void search(string token)
            {
                Stream datastream;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/services/suggestions/search");
                request.CookieContainer = cookieJar; // same cookejar is used as was used in login call
               // request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
               request.Headers.Add("x-csrf-token", token);
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.Accept = "application/x-cdf,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                String postData = "";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                postData = String.Format("param1={0}&param2={1}&param3={2}&param4={3}&param5={4}&param6={5}&param7={6}&param8={7}", "0", "1","1","1","0","1","2015-06-22","2015-06-22");
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                datastream = request.GetRequestStream();
                datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);


                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
                String sourceCode = "";
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream))
                {
                    sourceCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
```